# Stochastic integration by parts of geometric brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

My objective is to calculate the integral of a geometric brownian motion $Y=e^{\alpha t+\beta W_t}$, i.e. $$\int_{0}^T e^{\alpha s+\beta W_s}ds$$
and to characterize the moments of resulting random variable. If I make the transformation $g_t=x_ty_t$ with $x_t=e^{\alpha t}$ and $y_t=e^{\beta W_t}$ (where $\alpha,\beta>0$) and consider Ito integration by part, i.e.
\begin{equation}
d(x_ty_t)=x_tdy_t+y_tdx_t+dx_tdy_t
\end{equation}
I end up with:
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{\alpha T+\beta W_T} &=& 1+\int_{0}^T x_tdy+\int_{0}^T y_tdx_t+\int_{0}^Tdx_tdy_t\\
&=& 1+\int_{0}^T e^{\alpha s}e^{\beta W_s} \beta W_s dW_s +\int_{0}^T \alpha e^{\alpha s}e^{\beta W_s} ds+\int_{0}^T \alpha\beta e^{\alpha s}e^{\beta W_s}ds   dW_t
\end{eqnarray}
Here, I made use of $dx_t=\alpha x_tdt$, $dy_t=\beta y_t dW_t$ and $W_0=0$. After rearranging I get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha \int_{0}^T e^{\alpha s}e^{\beta W_s} ds &=& e^{\alpha T+\beta W_T}-1-\beta e^{\alpha s}\int_{0}^T e^{\beta W_s}  W_s dW_s  -\int_{0}^T \alpha\beta e^{\alpha s}e^{\beta W_s}dsdW_t
\end{eqnarray}
Now I am stuck since I do not know how to cope with the last two integrals. Any help and hints are very much appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Comment: The last integral is zero, $ds dW = 0$

Comment: And the second to last integral cannot be simplified further.

Comment: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't go any further than $\int e^{B_{t}+at}dt$. This is called the *integrated Geometric Brownian motion*. For references on its law  see

- ["The Integral of Geometric Brownian Motion"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1428449)
- ["On Some Exponential Functionals of Brownian Motion"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1427477)
- ["On the moments of the integrated geometric Brownian motion"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042718301730)

> Let $B$ stand for one-dimensional standard Brownian motion starting at $0$, and define the 'integral-exponential functional' of Brownian motion to be
> $$
> A_t^{(\mu)} = \int_0^te^{2\mu\tau + 2B_\tau} d\tau, \quad t \ge0, \mu \in \mathbb{R}. \tag{1.1}
> $$
> The main goal of this paper is to derive a new expression for the probability density function of $A_t^{(\mu)}$. Some expressions have previously been obtained for this density. Yor (1992a, Proposition 2) states that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> P(A_t^{(\mu)} \in du \mid B_t + \mu t = x)
> &=
> a_t(x,u) d u
> \\
> &=
> \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi t}}{u} \exp\left( \frac{x^2}{2t} - \frac{1}{2u} (1 + e^{2x})\right) \theta _ {e^x / u} (t) du, \tag{1.2}
> \end{align}
> $$
> where
> $$
> \theta_r(t) = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2 \pi^3 t}} \exp \left( \frac{\pi^2}{2t} \right) \int_0^\infty \exp \left( - \frac{y^2}{2t} \right) \exp (-r \cosh y) (\sinh y) \sin \left( \frac{\pi y}{t} \right) dy.
> $$

Comment: please do not paste images as answers

Comment: The problem is that a search engine can't read the text in an image, not that you copied it from somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the references which I checked carefully. It becomes now very clear for me how to proceed further, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, @Luke! If Thomas' answer helped you, see [How do I accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)